# How to get the website name and page title of a webpage

Tags: web-applications, web

I was wondering how programmatically to get the website name and page name of a webpage, or at least how to get a best guess.

For example, the website name of this question's webpage is Stack Overflow, and the page title is "How to get the website name and page title of a webpage".

I know it's not possible to get 100% accuracy (or even close), but it'd be great to at least be able to make an attempt at this. Programming language is irrelevant.

Comment: You mean from the server side or as a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're scraping another site with something like PHP Simple DOM Parser

```
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/s", $a, $matches);
```

That's everything in between the title. If you're going to attempt to extract a pseudo website name (assuming it's in the title) you can go about sorting out the first series of letters before it gets to a separator, usually " - ", " :: ", " -- " or some other variant. You would probably want to go look at 100 websites and find the most common.

Comment: That would get "web applications - How to get the website name and page title of a webpage - Stack Overflow" for this webpage. That's not quite what I'm looking for -- I'm looking for two things: "How to get the website name and page title of a webpage" and "Stack Overflow"

Comment: better use dom for html processing

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the page and pull the contents of the  tag to get the title. You should use an HTML parser to do this.

I'm not exactly sure how to get the name of the website. Can you just use the URL and format it cleanly? You could just take off the TLD and any subdomains and uppercase the first character. For example:

```
stackoverflow.com -> Stackoverflow
en.wikipedia.org -> Wikipedia
```

This obviously isn't a perfect solution, but it might be good enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As you said from the server side, it can be done in javascript this way,

for title

```
var title = document.title;
```

and for url

```
var location = document.location.href;
```